# Connecting Java Mision Control to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmc

I have a java application running on AWS EC2 instance(Amazon Linux AMI:Fedora). I am doing performance testing for my application and I have tested it using JMC with my local and remote servers, where I would log in using basic authentication; but I do not see any options in JMC console to connect to a remote server using certificates.

I was wondering if there was a way I could connect to EC2 from my local JMC console. I am new to AWS environment. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you wish to enable SSL authentication, I suggest reading this: https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/managing-java-flight-recorder-enabled-jvms-with-ssl, and maybe the JMX documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Comment: Another option, if you are using flight recordings, is to create them from commandline, using jcmd, and than transfer the JFR files to your local machine. See https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH177 or http://hirt.se/blog/?p=370